# How can I see enclosing folders in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, creative-cloud, mac

Across most Mac apps, windows have a feature that enables the user to open the enclosing folder(s) (this is done by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> and left click on the folder name).

[image]

However, Adobe CC apps have their own "tabbed" windows design, which doesn't seem to work the same way - and make it hard to easily navigate to the enclosing folder (for example when using the "Open Recent" menu very often).

This is the part I am fruitlessly trying to open enclosing folders from:

[image]

***How do I open the enclosing folder of a document in any Adobe CC app running on a Mac?***

Comment: Works *exactly* the same as it always has here. Command-click the title at the top (which changes when you change tabs).

Comment: I am on CC 2017.1 on a MacBook Pro retina 15 inches and it worked neither with my Logitech not with my Dell mouse. I edit the question

Comment: the **title** *not* the tab.

Comment: I don't see one

Comment: [Middle of the screen, above the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypmSc.png)

Comment: [Which I don't seem to have?](https://imgur.com/a/vhlOUpq)

Comment: Oh have that (ugly) Application frame active. You have to turn that off. (Window > Application Frame) That frame on a Mac is probably the WORST UI thing Adobe has done in 10 years. And it was only done to make Windows users feel more at "home". It serves no *real* purpose.

Comment: Sorry. I turn off that frame *immediately* upon the first launch. I forget it's there by default.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! Feel free to make that an answer if the question doesn't get canned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the **Application Frame** is *on* with new Adobe installs. The Application Frame was added to Macintosh versions so that Windows users would feel more comfortable on a Mac, but really it serves no *real* purpose on a Mac other than to limit your work to the frame. With multiple monitors it is *considerably* limiting and nothing more.

I personally *detest* the frame and immediately turn it off upon initial launch of an Adobe application.

So.. you have to **disable the Application Frame** by choosing `Window > Application Frame` to see the title of the documents. Which you can then <kbd>Command</kbd>-click to see the file tree.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is definitely part of the Mac+Adobe designer's workflow - hope it doesn't get voted for deletion as there isn't a lot on this online that I could find...

Comment: It *really* is more of a question for SuperUser though `:)` Technically *anything* asking about how an applications functions and *any* mention of an OS means it's not *really* a design question. *Design* is OS agnostic. `:)`

Comment: I don't particularly disagree, although the existence of the tags "workflow" might imply workflow issues are welcome. That being said, neither one of these windows systems is decent - now every time I resize an image the frame fits to it and sticks to the left of my screen... oh well

Comment: Well, the latter has been Mac behavior since it's inception.